# Locale specific index characters

Tags: language-agnostic, unicode, locale

I would like to have an index for a list. For example Android contact list has #,A-Z. But for many locales this doesn't cover all the locale specific characters.

How is the support for this in different programming languages? I took a quick look and in case of core Java I didn't see anything m

Somewhat related:
http://cldr.unicode.org/development/development-process/design-proposals/index-characters

Comment: FYI: you might benefit from this Area 51 [I18N & L10N proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12416/i18n-l10n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *VERY* good question!

As you note in the [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag, the important thing isn’t the programming language.  It’s the data set that you really need here. I know of no repository for such things.  The ᴄʟᴅʀ data do not yet contain this thing.  Here’s a simple table of sequences for various two-letter ɪsᴏ codes, plus a few extras for Asian sequences, written in Perl. This sort of thing could be the basis of a module.

It does require somewhat careful handling, because you can’t blindly titlecase the first grapheme in each element without regard to locale if you want an "uppercase"-ish set. That’s because of the Turkic I problem. I would install methods that pull out the sequences, and detect such things if they asked for something in the Turkic languages.

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

our %Alphabet = (
    en => [qw(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)],

    br => [qw(a b ch c'h d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u v w y z)],
    cy => [qw(a b c ch d dd e f ff g ng h i l ll m n o p ph r rh s t th u w y)],
    ga => [qw(a á b c d e é f g h i í l m n o ó p r s t u ú)],
    gd => [qw(a b c d e f g h i l m n o p r s t u)],

    la => [qw(a b c d e f g h i k l m n o p q r s t v x y z)],
    it => [qw(a b c d e f g h i k l m n o p q r s t u v z)],
    es => [qw(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n ñ o p q r s t u v w x y z)],
    es__traditional =>
          [qw(a b c ch d e f g h i j k l ll m n ñ o p q r s t u v w x y z)],
    eu => [qw(a b c ch d e f g h i j k l ll m n ñ o p q r s t ts tx tz u v w x y z)],
    rm => [qw(a b c d e f g h i j l m n o p q r s t u v x z)],
    ro => [qw(a ă â b c d e f g h i î j k l m n o p q r s ș t ț u v w x y z)],
    oc => [qw(a b c d e f g h i j l m n o p q r s t u v x z)],

    sw => [qw(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z å ä ö)],
    no => [qw(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z æ ø å)],
    is => [qw(a á b d ð e é f g h i í j k l m n o ó p r s t u ú v x y ý þ æ ö)],

    cz => [qw(a á b c č d ď e é ě f g h ch i í j k l m n ň o ó p q r ř s š t ť u ú ů v w x y ý z ž)],
    sk => [qw(a á ä b c č d ď dz dž e é f g h ch i í j k l ĺ ľ m n ň o ó ô p q r ŕ s š t ť u ú v w x y ý z ž)],
    sl => [qw(a b c č d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s š t u v z ž)],

    pl => [qw(a ą b c ć d e ę f g h i j k l ł m n ń o ó p r s ś t u w y z ź ż)],

    lt => [qw(a ą b c č d e ę ė f g h i į y j k l m n o p r s š t u ų ū v z ž)],
    lv => [qw(a ā b c č d e ē f g ģ h i ī j k ķ l ļ m n ņ o p r s š t u ū v z ž)],
    et => [qw(a b d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s š z ž t u v õ ä ö ü)],
    et__full =>
          [qw(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S Š Z Ž T U V W Õ Ä Ö Ü X Y)],
    et__simple => [qw(a b d e g h i j k l m n o p r s t u v õ ä ö ü)],

    hu => [qw(a á b c cS d dz dzs e é f g gy H i í j k l ly M n ny O ó ö ő p q r s sz t ty u ú ü ű v w x y z zs)],
    hu__traditional =>
          [qw(a á b c cs d dz dzs e é f g gy h i í j k l ly m n ny o ó ö ő p r s sz t ty u ú ü ű v z zs)],

    tr => [qw(a b c ç d e f g ğ h ı i j k l m n o ö p r s ş t u ü v y z)],
    az => [qw([a b c ç d e ə f g ğ h x ı i j k q l m n o ö p r s ş t u ü v y z)],
    az_1918_1939 =>
        [qw(a в c ç d e ə f g ƣ h i ь j k q l m n o ɵ p r s ş t u v x y z ƶ)],
    az_1939_1958 =>
        [qw(а б в г ғ д е ё ә ж з и й к қ л м н о ө п р с т у ү ф х h ц ч ҷ ш щ ъ ы ь э ю я ')],
    az_1958_1991 =>
        [qw(а б в г ғ д e ә ж з и ы ј к ҝ л м н о ө п р с т у ү ф х һ ч ҹ ш ')],
    az_1991_1992 =>
        [qw(a ä b c ç d e f g ğ h x ı i j k q l m n o ö p r s ş t u ü v y z)],

    he => [qw(α β γ δ ε ζ η θ ι κ λ μ ν ξ ο π ρ σ τ υ φ χ ψ ω)],

    ru => [qw(а б в г д е ж з и к л м н о п р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ы э ю я)],
    uk => [qw(а б в г ґ д е є ж з и і ї й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ь ю я)],
    mk => [qw(а б в г д ѓ е ж з ѕ и ј / к л љ м н њ о п р с т ќ / у ф х ц ч џ ш)],


    "HIRAGANA AIUEO" =>
         [qw(あ い う え お か き く け こ さ し す せ そ た ち つ て と な に ぬ ね の は ひ ふ へ ほ ま み む め も や ゆ よ ら り る れ ろ わ を ん)],
    "KATAKANA AIUEO" =>
         [qw(ア イ ウ エ オ カ キ ク ケ コ サ シ ス セ ソ タ チ ツ テ ト ナ ニ ヌ ネ ノ ハ ヒ フ ヘ ホ マ ミ ム メ モ ヤ ユ ヨ ラ リ ル レ ロ ワ ヲ ン)],
    "HALFWIDTH KATAKANA AIUEO" =>
        [qw(ｱ ｲ ｳ ｴ ｵ ｶ ｷ ｸ ｹ ｺ ｻ ｼ ｽ ｾ ｿ ﾀ ﾁ ﾂ ﾃ ﾄ ﾅ ﾆ ﾇ ﾈ ﾉ ﾊ ﾋ ﾌ ﾍ ﾎ ﾏ ﾐ ﾑ ﾒ ﾓ ﾔ ﾕ ﾖ ﾗ ﾘ ﾙ ﾚ ﾛ ﾜ ｦ ﾝ)],
    "KATAKANA IROHA" =>
         [qw(イ ロ ハ ニ ホ ヘ ト チ リ ヌ ル ヲ ワ カ ヨ タ レ ソ ツ ネ ナ ラ ム ウ ヰ ノ オ ク ヤ マ ケ フ コ エ テ ア サ キ ユ メ ミ シ ヱ ヒ モ セ ス)],
    "HIRAGANA IROHA" =>
         [qw(い ろ は に ほ へ と ち り ぬ る を わ か よ た れ そ つ ね な ら む う ゐ の お く や ま け ふ こ え て あ さ き ゆ め み し ゑ ひ も せ す)],
    "HALFWIDTH KATAKANA IROHA" =>
        [qw(ｲ ﾛ ﾊ ﾆ ﾎ ﾍ ﾄ ﾁ ﾘ ﾇ ﾙ ｦ ﾜ ｶ ﾖ ﾀ ﾚ ｿ ﾂ ﾈ ﾅ ﾗ ﾑ ｳ ﾉ ｵ ｸ ﾔ ﾏ ｹ ﾌ ｺ ｴ ﾃ ｱ ｻ ｷ ﾕ ﾒ ﾐ ｼ ﾋ ﾓ ｾ ｽ)],

    "HANGUL CHOSUNG" =>
         [qw(ㄱ ㄴ ㄷ ㄹ ㅁ ㅂ ㅅ ㅇ ㅈ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎ)],
    "HANGUL GANADA" =>
         [qw(가 나 다 라 마 바 사 아 자 차 카 타 파 하)],
    "CHINESE ZODIAC 10" =>
         [qw(甲 乙 丙 丁 戊 己 庚 辛 壬 癸)],
    "CHINESE ZODIAC 12" =>
         [qw(子 丑 寅 卯 辰 巳 午 未 申 酉 戍 亥)],

    "ZODIAC" => [qw(♈ ♉ ♊ ♋  ♌  ♍  ♎  ♏  ♐  ♑  ♒  ♓  )],

);

for my $a (\%Alphabet) {

    $$a{da} = $$a{no};
    $$a{fi} = $$a{no};

    $$a{de} = $$a{en};
    $$a{fr} = $$a{en};
    $$a{pt} = $$a{en};
}


1;
```

That should certainly be enough to get you started, though.

Comment: Suppose I was processing an index in French, and I ran across a word beginning with é ? It seems to me, I would consult your hash table above, and learn that there was no "é" in the list for French. (Since it's the same as the list for English). So my program would have to discover that "é" was just a variant of "e". Can you suggest an approach in Perl for doing that?

Comment: @egilchri Easy! Use `@sorted_data = Unicode::Collate::Locale->new(locale => "fr")->sort(@data)`.  The module uses the CLDR data, and is very extensive.  BTW, French sorts accents differently than most other languages.

Comment: So this works great, and I end up with a list of first letters:   (A  B  C  D  E  É  F  G  H  I  L  M  N  O  P  R  S  T  V )   What tells me that É should be collapsed into the E category? (BTW, this stuff so far is working like a charm, so many thanks. )

Comment: I forgot to put @tchrist in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm talking about a list of links at the top of my book index that will look like this: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P R S T U V W X Y Z: Clicking on a letter will link you to that part of the index. So what I want is to click on "E" and get to all "E" words, including those beginning with "É"

Comment: Then when you build your index, you need to group/sort by letter only (so a primary strength collation), not by diacritic (secondary strength) or by case (tertiary strength). That is certainly how I would do it.  But you could also normalize to NFD and removed combining marks if you were doing it manually. It just depends on the language.  It is safest to use the CLDR data for locale-tailoring based on country. After all, what will you otherwise  do when you get words like *œil-de-bœuf, œufs sur le plat*, or *œuvre*? In the constructor, just add a `level => 1` paremeter, and all will be well.

Comment: I have found this hash table very useful. A couple of things: Shouldn't "sw" be "sv"? Also, can you suggest a simple way I can add to the table? For example, I need Dutch (nl), and I don't see it. -- Dank U

Comment: Ok @tchrist, I guess I'm exposed as not being Dutch. It turns out, they use the Roman alphabet, like English. But my original question about adding to the structure, still stands.

Answer (score 2):

The CLDR page you mention describes an approach intended to address questions like this, and it says: “For CLDR 1.8, an initial set of index characters has been automatically generated” but warns: “WARNING: the automatic generation would only be a draft, for translators to tune, so any shortcomings could be fixed.” This might explain the situation if you cannot find support to it in programming languages yet.

But I suppose you could still use the data by extracting it directly from CLDR; it’s in the `main` data, element `<characters>`, subelement `<exemplarCharacters>` with `type="index"`.

For example, the Russian (ru) locale contains letters Е and Ё there, but I don’t think Russian indexes distinguish between those letters. For Finnish, V and W are both listed there, but traditionally they have not been distinguished (though this is changing). For Spanish, only single letters are listed, but in old tradition, the pair LL (denoting a single sound) is an index entry. So the details may need tuning or may be controversial, but the CLDR data is still a useful startung point.